# Problem with MvcSiteMapProvider 3.0 with ASP.NET MVC3 with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper, mvcsitemapprovider

I am having trouble getting MvcSiteMapProvider to work.
I have read the documentation on codeplex, and set it up just like they show.

I have referenced the MvcSiteMapProvider.dll to my web project.

The problem I'm having is that I cant access `@Html.MvcSiteMap()` at all. The `.MvcSiteMap` is missing in the HtmlHelper.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add references to web.config? As is described [here](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mvcsitemap).

**Edit:** Ok I downloaded it, made new MVC 3 project, referenced the dll and added the namespaces into two configs (one root and one in /Views/ folder) and I have it working. [image](http://i56.tinypic.com/amdxg8.png).

[image]

At first I did a mistake in doing Ctrl+C -> Ctrl+V when adding those namespaces into web configs. I selected whole codeblocks they provide and tried to paste them into web configs. Which was of course wrong. You have to select only those two lines

```
<add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" /> 
<add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
```

And add them into  element. Maybe you did it right, but I followed their steps and I got it working so you would have to provide your code if you did the same and it's not working for you.

Or if you won't get it working, then try to do what I did. Make new mvc project, add the sitemap, add it into config and check, if you are getting it in your View.

Comment: Yes I have. I have gone through all the steps on that site, but still cant get it to work. I using Areas so i got like three web.configs but i've only added the info to the default web.config.

Comment: You probably already tried to put that configuration into those separate web configs, right?

Comment: Ok I downloaded it, made new MVC 3 project, referenced the dll and added the namespaces into two configs (one root and one in /Views/ folder) and I have it working. [image](http://i56.tinypic.com/amdxg8.png)

Comment: Thanks for helping @dampe! I got it working in a new project, but not in the old, so I have to remove things until it start to work, i guess, and then add them one by one .. I having trouble viewing all the child nodes like test, test1-1, test1-2, test2 it only shows test1 and test2 .. But I guess thats a new question.

Comment: actually it **should be enough** to add the namespaces in the Views/web.config file